# Is shouldOverrideUrlLoading called for links within the same domain?

Tags: android, android-webview

I have a hybrid application where I have a WebView which is implementing the shouldOverrideUrlLoading method (both the deprecated and the newest version). This should take over control before loading any external links or certain links within my domain. Without going into specifics, the code looks roughtly like this:

```
private WebView mWebView;

mWebView.setWebViewClient(new myWebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if(url.isExternal() || url.contains("#specialCase")) {
            // Do actions
            return true;
        }
        return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
    }
});
```

I have noticed that all external links work properly, however shouldOverrideUrlLoading is not being called at all when the link is within my domain, so there is no way for me to detect those cases where I want to take over control.

The android documentation states

> Give the host application a chance to take over the control when a **new**
>   url is about to be loaded in the current WebView.

Does that new mean different domain? Is there anything I am missing or doing wrong? Any ideas on how to detect the user has clicked a link pointing to the same domain?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: maybe you can use if (url.startsWith("domain.com/")) and do your desire work

Comment: The problem is that shouldOverrideUrlLoading is never called at all if the url is within my domain, so I can't check anything.

Comment: use this client with existing one      : webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
                super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);
            }

        });

Comment: Thank you, I tried but doesn't seem to make any difference

Comment: u are using HTML data or just URL?

Comment: Just the usual <a href="url">

Comment: i am using this type:  webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("http://www.ANY.com",s,"text/html","UTF-8",null);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the reason why shouldOverrideUrlLoading was never been called.

Apparently the method is only called when the actual loading is about to start. Our web application is a single-page application, hence even though the URL changes, no new page is loaded and shouldOverrideUrlLoading is not called.